# Change the property of a object in Angular which generated using a button click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, barcode

In a project, I've used JsBarcode library to generate barcodes. Here I've used ng-click directive to generate the barcode in angular. Here I need to change the properties of generated barcode using the angular data binding feature. I tried in everyway I understood but it didn't work. Finally, I added the data bindings to the same function and now I have to click the button to update the barcode. Please, can anyone help me to achieve this using angular data binding feature?

This is the part of the script which I use to generate the barcode

```
$scope.CreateTable = function (){
window.setTimeout(function () {
            JsBarcode('#barcode', ProductDescription, {
                //format: 'CODE39',
                flat:true,
                displayValue: false,
                margin:0,
                marginLeft: 20,
                marginRight: 0,
                marginTop: 0,
                marginBottom: 0,               
                height: $scope.calculateHeight(),
                width: (1 + ((((($scope.paperSelection / $scope.numberOfColumns)-60) - (31.5 + 9.9 * ($scope.ProductDescription.length))) / (3.5 + 1.1 * ($scope.ProductDescription.length))) - 1) * 0.1)
            });
        });
}

$scope.calculateHeight = function () {
        if (($scope.showNameOnTop == undefined || $scope.showNameOnTop == false) && ($scope.showNameOnBottom == undefined || $scope.showNameOnBottom == false) && ($scope.showDetails == undefined || $scope.showDetails == false)) {
            return $scope.heightOfSticker - 30;
        }
        else if (($scope.showNameOnTop == true && ($scope.showNameOnBottom == false || $scope.showNameOnBottom == undefined) && ($scope.showDetails == false || $scope.showDetails == undefined)) || ($scope.showNameOnBottom == true && ($scope.showNameOnTop == false || $scope.showNameOnTop == undefined) && ($scope.showDetails == false || $scope.showDetails == undefined)) || ($scope.showDetails == true && ($scope.showNameOnBottom == false || $scope.showNameOnBottom == undefined) && ($scope.showNameOnTop == false || $scope.showNameOnTop == undefined))) {
            return $scope.heightOfSticker - 40;
        }
        else if (($scope.showNameOnTop == true && $scope.showNameOnBottom == true && ($scope.showDetails == undefined || $scope.showDetails == false)) || ($scope.showNameOnTop == true && $scope.showDetails == true && ($scope.showNameOnBottom == undefined || $scope.showNameOnBottom == false)) || ($scope.showNameOnBottom == true && $scope.showDetails == true && ($scope.showDetails == undefined || $scope.showDetails == false))) {
            return $scope.heightOfSticker - 60;
        }
    };
```

I just need to change the **height** after the barcode is loaded without running the **CreateTable** always.

Comment: are you planning to capture any event to change the height ? or how do you want to change the height ?

Comment: I need to change the height of the barcode after it's loaded (need to change the **height** property of JsBarcode) . Let's say I have input type number and I need to change the value of height property according to the given input using angular data binding feature. How can it be done ?

Comment: try with the answer that I gave you that might work@Thidasa

Comment: `ngStyle` will do that - https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/docs/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

Comment: @ThidasaParanavitharana did you try the answer I posted ??

Comment: @BOSS I tried changing the size of the div. I won't work. Even to change the width of the barcode I tried changing the width of the div. But didn't work. The only way I have to change the width of the barcode by changing the value of the width property of barcode it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) option when creating your bar code . Depending on condition you can change the parent div. Also try setting the bar code height 100% which will take full space of the parent div and change the parent div height accordingly with ng-class.

```
<p ng-class="{class1 : expression1, class2 : expression2}">Changing css value</p>
```

Comment: But changing the div height does not help. I tried to change the height of barcode by changing the div which the barcode is included. But it takes the default height (100px) even though the div is less than it. The only way I can change the height of the barcode is by changing the value of the height property of it.

Comment: could you make the height of bar code 100% then try ?

Comment: I solved the issue by adding barcode generating function call in checkbox using ng-checked. 
Thanks for the help anyway